# Custom index field returning "Server Error in '/' Application. Could not find add method: AddComputedIndexField"

Tags: solr, azure, indexing

I am trying to create a commuted index field in sitecore 9 but can't get the configuration to work. 
I have a local environment which is running Solr and also environment is Azure.

I have added the following configuration to my indexing patch config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
      <indexConfigurations>
        <defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
          <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
            <field fieldName="icon_services" returnType="string">Sitecore.Foundation.Indexing.Infrastructure.Fields.ImageURLComputedField, Sitecore.Foundation.Indexing</field>
          </fields>
        </defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
      </indexConfigurations>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

This configuration throws the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>       Could not find add method: AddComputedIndexField (type: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration)
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: Sitecore.Exceptions.RequiredObjectIsNullException: Could not find add
>   method: AddComputedIndexField (type:
>   Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrIndexConfiguration)

My code for computed index:

```
public class ImageURLComputedField : IComputedIndexField
  {
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    public string ReturnType { get; set; }

    public object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
    {
      Assert.ArgumentNotNull(indexable, "indexable");
      string url = null;
      try
      {
        Item item = indexable as SitecoreIndexableItem;

        // This field only works for items uder /sitecore/content that have a layout
        if (item == null
            || item.Visualization.Layout == null
            || !item.Paths.FullPath.StartsWith(
                    Sitecore.Constants.ContentPath,
                    System.StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
          return null;
        }
        ImageField img = item.Fields["Icon"];

        return img == null || img.MediaItem == null ? null : MediaManager.GetMediaUrl(img.MediaItem);
      }
      catch (WebException webExc)
      {
        Log.Warn(string.Format("Failed to html index {0} ({1}): {2}", indexable.Id, url, webExc.Message), webExc, this);
      }
      catch (Exception exc)
      {
        Log.Error(string.Format("An error occurred when indexing {0}: {1}", indexable.Id, exc.Message), exc, this);
      }
      return null;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Sitecore 8.2 there was one additional xml tag in the config, `documentOptions`. I don't have Sitecore 9 instance running at the moment, but I expect it's the same:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
      <indexConfigurations>
        <defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
          <documentOptions> <!-- MISSING -->
            <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
              <field fieldName="icon_services" returnType="string">Sitecore.Foundation.Indexing.Infrastructure.Fields.ImageURLComputedField, Sitecore.Foundation.Indexing</field>
            </fields>
          </documentOptions> <!-- MISSING -->
        </defaultSolrIndexConfiguration>
      </indexConfigurations>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This saved my life. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the following configuration to make custom field shown in the solr Index.I am trying to add it to a custom index(not default indexes).Adding FieldMap tag will map the field and index it.

```
 <documentOptions type="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.SolrDocumentBuilderOptions, Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider">
            <include hint="list:AddIncludedTemplate">
              <CustomDetails>{B713DC5E-1A10-40D5-A9C0-3DFF1431D05B}</CustomDetails>
            </include>
            <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
              <field fieldName="FacetCategory" returnType="string">Foundation.Location.Repository.FacetsComputedField, Foundation.Location</field>
            </fields>
          </documentOptions>
         <fieldMap ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/defaultSolrIndexConfiguration/fieldMap">
           <fieldNames hint="raw:AddFieldByFieldName">
                        <fieldType fieldName="FacetCategory" returnType="string" />
          </fieldNames>
        </fieldMap>
```

Answer (score 0):

Google lands me on this page, however, I had a different error:

```
HttpException (0x80004005): Could not find add method: AddPrefetch (type: System.String)
```

After a long investigation I figured that if some other library is referenced by `Sitecore` related DLLs, you may get some weird errors, anyway I figured that `Unicorn` related DLLs (`Rainbow .*.dll, Unicorn.dll`),  were missing, as I only copied the project DLL to the Bin, while the config files related to `Unicorn` were still there under `App_config`. Hope it helps. Either delete unnecessary config files or make sure any module/package there in config files has the relevant DLLs in the bin folder.

Answer (score -1):

I added the following patch file for Azure search to work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <contentSearch>
      <indexConfigurations>
        <defaultCloudIndexConfiguration>
          <documentOptions>
            <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
              <field fieldName="icon_services" returnType="string">Sitecore.Foundation.Indexing.Infrastructure.Fields.ImageURLComputedField, Sitecore.Foundation.Indexing</field>
            </fields>
          </documentOptions>
        </defaultCloudIndexConfiguration>
      </indexConfigurations>
    </contentSearch>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Arun, your answer looks exactly the same as the accepted answer. Is there any reason you decided to post it as a separate answer?